# 'Card' Cannot Be Used as JSX Component

Tags: typescript, next.js13

When I'm coding Next.js on Visual Studio Code, I encounter the following error:

'Card' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its type 'OverridableComponent<CardTypeMap<{}, "div">>' is not a valid JSX element type. Type 'OverridableComponent<CardTypeMap<{}, "div">>' is not assignable to type '(props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => ReactNode'. Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'*

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardContent>
        <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', marginBottom: 5.5, alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
          <Avatar sx={{ boxShadow: 3, marginRight: 4, color: 'common.white', backgroundColor: `${color}.main` }}>
            {icon}
          </Avatar>
          <IconButton size='small' aria-label='settings' className='card-more-options' sx={{ color: 'text.secondary' }}>
            <DotsVertical />
          </IconButton>
        </Box>
        <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: 600, fontSize: '0.875rem' }}>{title}</Typography>
        <Box sx={{ marginTop: 1.5, display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', marginBottom: 1.5, alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
          <Typography variant='h6' sx={{ mr: 2 }}>
            {stats}
          </Typography>
          <Typography
            component='sup'
            variant='caption'
            sx={{ color: trend === 'positive' ? 'success.main' : 'error.main' }}
          >
            {trendNumber}
          </Typography>
        </Box>
        <Typography variant='caption'>{subtitle}</Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  )
}
```

Comment: Glad to have you on Stack Overflow! Before we can help you figure out a solution for the issue you're facing, I'd like to ask you to revisit your question and review the guide for [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here. In particular, your formatting is a bit off here, making the code difficult to read, and it's not clear what steps you've taken to try and resolve the issue.